# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. NODE-server, I have applied an origin to Cors

Tags: node.js, http, server, axios, cors

I realize there has been a million questions on these, and I know since I have clicked on each one and none have solved my problem.

My cors setup:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",//'https://leetbattle.vercel.app', have tried both, none work
      methods: ["GET, POST"],
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      credentials: true
    },
    forceNew: true,
    reconnection: false,
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    allowEIO3: true
  });
```

The API call I have server-side:

```
const handleRun = async (roomName: string, playerNumber: string) => {
      playerNumberRun = playerNumber
      roomNameRun = roomName
      app.route("/run").post((req: any, res: any) => { 
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        data.source_code = req.body.code.code;
        axios({
          url: process.env.VM_URL,
          method: "POST",
          data: data,
        })
          .then(async (req: any, res: any) => {
            //first call generates a token
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // 1 sec
            //after waiting, use the token to get the res.data.stdout which is
            //what I want to send to frontend using sockets
            axios
              .get(process.env.VM_URL+ '/'+ req.data.token)
              .then((req: any, res: any) => {
                if (!req) {
                  console.log("no output");
                }
                output.codeOutput = req.data.stdout;
                output.errorOutput = req.data.stderr;
                sendCode(roomNameRun, output, playerNumberRun);
              })
          })
          .catch((err: Error) => {
            io.to(roomNameRun).emit("serverError", playerNumberRun);
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
      
    };
```

The call to the route that I have on my front-end:

```
const onExecute = async (code) => {
    setRunIsLoading(true);
    socket.emit("run", gameCode, playerNumber);
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: BACKEND_URL+"/run",
      data: { code },
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      setRunIsLoading(false);
    });
  };
```

I am deploying with Vercel and Heroku (backend)
You can try out the error for yourself on https://leetbattle.vercel.app/

ALL OF THIS WORKS ON LOCALHOST, which confuses me even more.

You will notice that the socket-stuff works but the request when you press "run" is pending in the network tab (with a pre-flight request), before after about 30seconds getting cancelled and sending you the error message in the title.

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help, as this is (probably) the last error before I can "finalize" the project. I am honestly considering switching to GraphQL instead of REST for this, but that is a different issue.

I will tell you everything that you want to know. Thanks.

Comment: What is `app.route().post()` doing inside a function?  That looks like it's likely  wrong.  Where is `handleRun()` called from?

Comment: when the user presses "run"-button, I emit a signal to the server which triggers handleRun() AND make a post-request to the route. I also send the playerNumber who pressed it and the roomNumber.

Comment: Yeah, that is not a correct design.  You can't install a route just for an upcoming request.  For one, there's no way to uninstall that route so now it's permanently installed.  And, then the next time you call that function it gets installed again as a duplicate (which creates a memory leak).  And, that route isn't installed just for one user, it's installed for all users.  Routes are global.  They apply to the whole server and all incoming requests from all users.  You need a different design for that type of code.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I will rewrite it into something more user-specific. thank you for the advice! I probably wouldn't have thought about it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You just enabled cors for Socket.io. You should enable express.js cors for your api calls too!
Use this to enable it: [Enabling cors in Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Comment: could you elaborate please? I added a call to 'cors()' to my routes but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: also tried  added configurations on origin to app.use(cors({...})

Comment: Please share your browser console shot to see your request errors. As you may know, CORS requests are being handled in 2 steps. first a check request with the OPTIONS method. Then main request.